# Is it wise to use Glide to load XML vectors

Tags: android, vector, drawable

Does Glide know to differentiate between images and vectors? Is there any advantage for loading an XML vector using Glide in terms of memory usage and cache management?

```
GlideApp.with(imageView)
                .load(R.drawable.my_xml_vector)
                .into(imageView);
```

If I choose to load it directly, should I worry about recycling it?

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_xml_vector);
```

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, If you are loading large images you should scale the image as per your need before using. In some cases not doing so, might produce `outOfMemoryError`. You can use following method to scale the image before loading.

```
iv.setImageBitmap(decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.big_image));

    private static Bitmap decodeResource(Resources res, int id) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        for (options.inSampleSize = 1; options.inSampleSize <= 32; options.inSampleSize++) {
            try {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, id, options);
                Log.d(TAG_LOG, "Decoded successfully for sampleSize " + options.inSampleSize);
                break;
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError outOfMemoryError) {
                // If an OutOfMemoryError occurred, we continue with for loop and next inSampleSize value
                Log.e(TAG_LOG, "outOfMemoryError while reading file for sampleSize " + options.inSampleSize
        + " retrying with higher value");
            }
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
```

In some cases, `Glide` fails to load vector images or partially load it. The best possible way I have seen is to load vector images is as a placeholder or as an error image like

```
GlideApp.with(mContext) .load("") .error(R.drawable.my_vector) .into(holder.imageView);
```